# efficiently sample from modified arma::vec object

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I am using Rcpp to speed up some R code.  However, I'm really struggling with types - since these are foreign in R. Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <algorithm>
//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector fun(SEXP Pk, int k, int i, const vec& a, const mat& D) {
  // this is dummy version of my actual function - with actual arguments.;
  // I'm guessing SEXP is going to need to be replaced with something else when it's called from C++ not R.;
  return D.col(i);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector f(const arma::vec& assignment, char k, int B, const mat& D) {
    uvec k_ind = find(assignment == k);
    NumericVector output(assignment.size());  // for dummy output.

    uvec::iterator k_itr = k_ind.begin();

    for(; k_itr != k_ind.end(); ++k_itr) {
        // this is R code, as I don't know the best way to do this in C++;
        k_rep = sample(c(assignment[assignment != k], -1), size = B, replace = TRUE);

        output = fun(k_rep, k, *k_itr, assignment, D);
        // do something with output;
    }

    // compile result, ultimately return a List (after I figure out how to do that.  For right now, I'll cheat and return the last output);
    return output;
}
```

The part I'm struggling with is the random sampling of `assignment`.  I know that `sample` has been implemented in `Rarmadillo`.  However, I can see two approaches to this, and I'm not sure which is more efficient/doable.

### Approach 1:

- Make a table of the`assignment` values.  Replace `assignment == k` with -1 and set its "count" equal to 1.
- sample from the table "names" with probability proportional to the count.

### Approach 2:

- Copy the relevant subset of the `assignment` vector into a new vector with an extra spot for -1.
- Sample from the copied vector with equal probabilities.

I want to say that approach 1 would be more efficient, except that `assignment` is currently of type `arma::vec`, and I'm not sure how to make the table from that - or how much of a cost there is to converting it to a more-compatible format.   I think I could implement Approach 2, but I'm hoping to avoid the expensive copy.

Thanks for any insights you can provide.

Comment: You can use `sample` directly in Rcpp. See the bottom of this page: https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/210_rcpp_functions.html#list-of-r-like-functions

Comment: I find the R-C++ mixture rather confusing. Can you provide an R only solution with sample input and expected output?

Comment: @MelissaKey: I would recommend you re-read the posts on the RcppArmadillo `sample` function you can find at the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) and then rework your question.  Right now we are not really in a position to help you.

Comment: Thanks for trying.  I'm working through it - as I come up with more specific questions that I can't find answers to through the vast resources you have put out, I will ask them.

Answer (score -1):

many variable declaration is not coherent with the assignment made by you, like assignment = k is impossible to compare as assignment has real value and k is a char. as the queston is bad written I feel free to change the variables type. this compile..

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec fun(const Rcpp::NumericVector& Pk, int k, unsigned int i, const arma::ivec& a, const arma::mat& D)
{
  return D.col(i);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix f(const arma::ivec& assignment, int k, unsigned int B, const arma::mat& D) 
{
  arma::uvec k_ind = find(assignment == k);
  arma::ivec KK = assignment(find(assignment != k));
  //these 2 row are for KK = c(assignment[assignment != k], -1)  
  //I dont know what is this -1 is for, why -1 ? maybe you dont need it.
     KK.insert_rows(KK.n_rows, 1);
     KK(KK.n_rows - 1) = -1;

  arma::uvec k_ind_not = find(assignment != k);
  Rcpp::NumericVector k_rep(B);
  arma::mat output(D.n_rows,k_ind.n_rows);  // for dummy output.

  for(unsigned int i =0; i < k_ind.n_rows ; i++) 
  {
    k_rep = Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample(KK, B, true);

    output(arma::span::all, i) = fun(k_rep, k, i, assignment, D);
    // do something with output;
  }

  // compile result, ultimately return a List (after I figure out how to do that.  For right now, I'll cheat and return the last output);
  return Rcpp::wrap(output);
}
```

this is not optimized (as the question is bogus), this is badly written, beccause as I think R would be sufficiently faster in searching index of a vector (so do this in R and implemement only fun in Rcpp)...is not useful to waste time here, there are other problems that need a solver implemented in Rcpp , not this searching stuff...
but this is not a useful question as you are asking more for an algorithm than for example signature of function